# How can I recreate the greenhouse effect in my car?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, infrared-radiation

I am trying to preheat my car during winter mornings using the greenhouse effect. I understand the greenhouse effect in cars works by visible light passing through the glass, with most UV and infrared being blocked by the glass. The visible light is either absorbed by the interior and turned into heat or reflected largely as infrared and later turned into heat. Darker colors absorb more light.

I set a 500W halogen spotlight inches from my car windshield and turned it on. Unfortunately, after approximately 1 hour, I do not see any increase in interior temperature. What might I be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

500W is the power input, not the light output.  Halogen bulbs have a [Luminous efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficacy) of less than 5%.  So if your windshield blocks IR, you're probably getting less than 20W of that power into the car.  It's going to be difficult to measure the effect of that.

Full sunlight on a windshield could be more than 1500W.

Comment: And most of those $20 w$ are probably scaping out of the car as well haha.

Answer (score 1):

Greenhouses are viable because the Sun's irradiation is (1) free and (2) strong (maximum of about 1 kW/m²). These advantages aren't available with your current configuration.

To heat your car, you'd want a mechanism that offers at least 100% efficiency (e.g., a resistance heater or heat pump) that transfers energy directly to the interior by dissipation (e.g., an electric heater) or convection (e.g., by convected heated air, sometimes used at truck stops, as shown below, although the efficiency here would be degraded from heat loss through the duct insulation).

[image]